# I'm trying to setup an array but for some reason the array isn't identified as one

Tags: javascript, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQWmU.png)

In my code i was trying to make an array. I'm trying to make it play the names with the numbers (down from 35 to 31). But for some reason when i preview it it shows nothing. Is there anyone who understands what i've done wrong?

(I'm extremely new to coding so please treat me like you're talking to a 5 year old.)

Thank you for your time

Comment: No one should treat you like you are 5, but they _should_ ask you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question.

Comment: please insert the code directly, within a code block

Comment: Try putting this into a code snippet or jsFiddle. It will be easier for us to find an answer. It looks fine now, but obviously there is something going on.

Comment: I've copied it off a youtube video i've been using to learn the basics of coding. Here is the link in case it explains something about the problem that i happened to miss https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVv9irU9WKk

Answer (score 0):

This works and shows several *alert* window.

```
<html>
<head>
<tit1e> my script </tit1e>
<script type="text/javascript">
myNane = "Sam";
foodType = "bananas";
numberFlatten = 9;
numberTotal = 35;

myArray = new Array("sam", "cian", "1ouis ", "max", "hoi");
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    alert(myArray[i] + "ate " + (numberTotal-1) + " " + foodType + " ")
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks online OCR!